# How to use include without mixing with existing content

Tags: php, include

I have a page and I want to add a banner and text that is located outside in another php. I use the include function, and it works fine but, what was already on the site affects it when adding the new code. That is, I add include so that it reads the php file, it reads it fine, but it affects the style of what was already there.

From the index I place it like this:

```
<!-- BANNER -->

<?php
include('banner_a/banner_a.php');
?>


<?php require './sections/featured.php'; ?>
<?php require './sections/featured-stores.php'; ?>
<?php require './sections/categories.php'; ?>


<!-- FOOTER -->
<?php require './sections/footer.php'; ?>
```

And in banner_a.php is the banner code with the styles included. I don't know how to close and maintain the style of banner_a.php so that it doesn't affect the index code that was already there. How do I lock it up so it doesn't affect the rest?

I tried include and it works, but when I add it inside my index, what was already on the page is affected (styles) when include calls the external php.

The external code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="banner_a/assets/web/assets/icons/icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="banner_a/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="banner_a/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="banner_a/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
  <link rel="preload" as="style" href="banner_a/assets/file/css/additional.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="banner_a/assets/file/css/additional.css" type="text/css">
    <div class="overlay" style="opacity: 0.4; background-color: rgb(68, 121, 217);">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="card col-12 col-lg-10">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <div class="card-box align-center">
                        <h4 class="card-title asd-fonts-style align-center as-4 display-5"><strong>Quieres ser miembro de Buterffly?</strong></h4>
                        <p class="text asd-fonts-style as-4 display-7">adquiere los planes especiales que tenemos para ti</p>
                        <div class="section-btn mt-3"><a class="btn btn-warning display-4" href="https://url.com">Ver planes</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It sounds like more of a CSS (and possibly HTML) problem than a PHP problem.  You may be mixing up different CSS styles, perhaps operating on a false assumption that PHP somehow separates these included files into different pages.  Can you provide a specific example of the resulting client-side code and styling which isn't working as expected?

Comment: I already added the banner_a.php code

Comment: And how exactly is that HTML styled incorrectly or unexpectedly?  It really just sounds like you're misunderstanding how CSS works in general.  Styles used on the page apply to the whole page.  If your styles aren't doing what you want or expect, you'd change them.  This has exactly nothing to do with PHP's `include` or `require` operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid the style in `banner_a.php` to affects other elements of the site.

You need to use CSS `class` and `id` to specify the style in `banner_a.php`.

You should create and external CSS file to manage the style of your website.

Look at here for some examples : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp